# Make a loop to separate each rows separately into one XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I activated SQL Server broker
I deal with XML in query tables it is working well
I encountered a problem sometimes, it sends two row together in one XML
as the following example:

```
declare @XML xml = '<row TableName="tblUsers" Action="INSERT" ID="1" AccountName="test1" />
                    <row TableName="tblUsers" Action="UPDATE" ID="2" AccountName="test2" />'

DECLARE @count INT;
SET @count = 1;

WHILE @count<= (select Count(*) from 
@XML.nodes('/*') T(c))
BEGIN
   PRINT @count
   // How do get the first row here and then the next
   SET @count = @count + 1;
END;
```

How can I make a loop in SQL Server to separate each row separately so that I can deal with this row, then the next, and then the next

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop for that? SQL Server operates best in a set-based fashion - you can separate the individual `row` elements in a set-based query to be consumed by other insert/select/update database operations.

Comment: thank you sir SQL Server broker Receive two rows at the same time. I needed, after receiving the two rows , separate each one separately, then convert each row to json , and then send it to api. If i convert the two rows without separating them to json, the conversion output will be wrong, so I was looking for a solution to separate the two rows. I apologize for the bad language

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @XML xml = '<row TableName="tblUsers" Action="INSERT" ID="1" AccountName="test1" />
                <row TableName="tblUsers" Action="UPDATE" ID="2" AccountName="test2" />'

DECLARE @count INT;
SET @count = 1;

WHILE @count<= (select Count(*) from @XML.nodes('/*') T(c))
BEGIN
   --PRINT @count
   select _XML
   from
   (
     SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.a) as _ROW ,a.query('.') as _XML  from @XML.nodes('/*') T(a)
   )a where _ROW = @count

   SET @count = @count + 1;
END;
```

Comment: thank you sir
SQL Server broker Receive two rows  at the same time.
I needed, after receiving the two rows , separate each one separately, then convert each row to json , and then send it to api.
If i convert the two rows without separating them to json, the conversion output will be wrong, so I was looking for a solution to separate the two rows.
I apologize for the bad language

Comment: I can't accept it as a correct answer
Get an error from the site . You can accept your own answer in 2 days